# Octave funny error - Cannot define function

Tags: c++, function, octave, gnu, archive

This is my code:

I get the error just after the whiles or the ifs, I don't know how to solve it. Say something like: "Display all 3669 possibilities (y or n)" and starts showing and endless list of things I haven't asked for :p

I must be defining the function wrongly but I can't find where. It would be very helpful, If you'd told me what the problem is or how I should do to solve it.

R, Rer and V are vectors; pc,dg and cs are numbers

```
function [R,Rer] = er_dig(V,pc,dg,cs) 
i=0;
dg_aux=V;
while (abs(rem(dg_aux,1))!=0)
    dg_aux=dg_aux.*10;
    i++;
endwhile

Rer= (V.*dg)./100 + dg.*(10^(-i));


if (Rer<1)
    Rer_aux=Rer;
    k=0;
    while (abs(rem(Rer_aux,1))>0)
        Rer_aux=Rer_aux.*10;
        k++;
    endwhile

    if (Rer_aux>=10)
        k--;
    endif

    j=1;
    while (j<=dim(V))
        validador=(Rer(j)*(10^(k+cs))-fix(Rer(j)*(10^(k+cs-1)))*10);
        if (validador>=2)
            Rer(j) = (fix(Rer(j)*(10^(k+cs-1))) +1)/(10^(k+cs-1));
        elseif
            Rer(j) = (fix(Rer(j)*(10^(k+cs-1))))/(10^(k+cs-1));
        endif
    j++;
    endwhile


    R=V;
    i=1;
    while (i<=dim(V))
        R(i) = fix(R(i)*10^(k+cs-1))/10^(k+cs-1);
        i++;
    endwhile

elseif
    Rer_aux=Rer;
    k=0;
    while(Rer_aux>1)
        Rer_aux=Rer_aux./10;
        k++;
    endwhile


    j=1;
    while(j<=dim(V))
        validador=(Rer(j)*(10^(-k+cs))-fix(Rer(j)*(10^(-k+cs-1)))*10);
        if(validador>=2)
            Rer(j) = (fix(Rer(j)*(10^(-k+cs))) +1)/(10^(-k+cs));
        elseif
            Rer(j) = (fix(Rer(j)*(10^(k+cs))))/(10^(k+cs));
        endif
    j++;
    endwhile


    R=V;
    i=1;
    while(i<=dim(V))
        R(i) = fix(R(i)*10^(-k+cs))/10^(-k+cs);
        i++;
    endwhile

endif
```

endfunction

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling that from a script or copying and paste? If you are copying and paste and have a double tab anywhere in your code, two tabs are for autocomplete. Try to put that code in a file and call it from the Octave prompt specifying the path to the file. Use spaces for indentation if you want to copy and paste code like that.

Comment: That's what I did, thank you for your answer. That was the problem